# iPhone and MySQL

Tags: iphone, mysql, xcode, insert, uitextfield

First I need to say that I am new to iPhone development, so please I need you to be specific!

I'm developing an application for School scientific project,the question is: How can I insert data into a mysql table from UITextFields on the iPhone?

On my application I have 3 UITextFields, so I need to insert those UITextFields values into the mysql table. It doesn't matter the way you know to do that, I'm in a hurry and I just wanna to put it to work.

1-I working with this PHP code

```
<?php


if (isset ($_GET["matricula"]))
    $matricula = $_GET["matricula"];

else 

    $matricula = "ELO";



$sql="INSERT INTO chatitems (user, message, matricula) VALUES ('$_GET[user]','$_GET[messages]','$_GET[matricula]')";



$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

//$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (matricula) values('$matricula');";
$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($con);
if ($res) {
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "faild";
}// end else

?>
```

And I insert this CODE on my application(Xcode 4.1)

2

```
- (IBAction)insert:(id)sender
{
// create string contains url address for php file, the file name is phpFile.php, it receives parameter :name
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/phpFile.php?name=%@",txtName.text];
//NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/phpFile.php?name=%@",txtMatricula.text];

// to execute php code
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

// to receive the returend value
NSString *strResult = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];

NSLog(@"%@", strResult);


NSString *cont11 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/UEUO/insertMT.php?name=%@",txtName.text];
NSString *cont21 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/UEUO/insertMT.php?matricula=%@",txtMatricula.text];

NSData *cont12 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cont11]];
NSData *cont22 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cont21]];

NSString *cont13 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:cont12 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
NSLog(@"%@", cont13);

NSString *cont23 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:cont22 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
NSLog(@"%@", cont23);

}
```

This code works fine for only one `UItextField`, I need three3.

Repenting: How can I insert the values of three UITextFields into a MySql table using PHP and C++?

Please anything is helpful, if you know how please help me or send me a tutorial or a piece of code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP script is looking for 3 parameters passed from a single request.

Your iPhone code is sending 2 different requests with 1 parameter each.

Your iPhone code should be sending 1 request with 3 parameters set, as with this sort of request:

```
NSString *cont11 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/UEUO/insertMT.php?name=%@&matricula=%@&message=%@",txtName.text, txtMatricula.text, txtMessage.text];
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cont11]];
```

I should also point out that you haven't sanitized your inputs.  That's really bad.  Sanitize your inputs.

Comment: So many thanks man it worked perfect for me!You're the guy.As soon as possible i pretend to post i tutorial explaining this to help other people!SO MANY THANKS YOU SAVED MY LIFE!CONGRATS YOU ARE THE GUY!